# Positioning elements inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to put a down chevron to my carousel but the chevron appears outside of the carousel container. I want to have something like this :

http://www.yummygum.com

my HTML code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-rounded" src="images/biz%20bznner.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container ccontainers">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1 class="animated rubberBand 1">You have a project? Let Us Do it for you</h1>
          <h3 class="animated bounceInLeft">We will do your projects with the best prices</h3>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary animated shake 1" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="chevron-down" href="#myCarousel" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden"true"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

my CSS:

```
.carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
background-image: none;
}

.carousel .item {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel {
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%; 
}


.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    padding: 0.5em;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.chevron-down{
    **margin-bottom:100px** //THIS DOES NOT WORK
    margin-left: 50%;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.carousel-caption a{
    background-color: orangered;
    border-color: darkred;
    margin-top: 1em; 
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
  text-align: center;  
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

so in the .chevron-down class margin left works but when I try to vertically move the chevron it does not do anything.. what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
.chevron-down {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKXxoz)